# What does "Number of points" mean when you select the Parameter Range option

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, azure-machine-learning-service

What does "Number of points" mean on the various models when you select the Parameter Range option for Create Trainer Mode.  Can anyone shed light on what this parameter means.

The Azure ML Studio documentation does not mention this parameter, either in [the documentation for the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/two-class-logistic-regression) or in the [documentation to tune hyperparameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/tune-model-hyperparameters).

[image]

Comment: if the person who down voted can explain why, that would be helpful for future posts.

Answer (score 0):

That is the number of points that are extracted from your parameter range. Ad example if your range is [0,100] and "number of points" is 5. The algorithm will be tested using the values 0,25,50,75,100.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought, but from the Azure documentation, it seems that those values are configured so as to be inputs into the tune hyperparameters tool, but within the tune hyperparameters tool, you set how many runs on a random sweep.  So would the number of points be used if I were to select the "Entire Grid" option on the hyperparameter sweep tool then?

Comment: @MikeBaron personally I think that AzureML documentation is really bad. If you can switch to Python or R it would be better in term of support. Beside that: If you set the range and the number of points, when you run the sweep tool the grid will be given by the combination of all the points that you have set. If you leave some parameters unset automatic values (depending on the algorithms) are used for that parameters. If you don't set any parameter a grid is automatically generated by the system.

Comment: yah agreed re: documentation.  It just feels like an unfinished product.  We will see where it goes.  So I just ran the hyperparameter tuning tool on a model that had 3 parameters.  I set the number of points to 5 for each... I would expect it to run the equivalent of 0,25,50,75,100 based on your example for each parameter for a total of 625 different combinations... I chose "entire grid" expecting it to use what I set, but it ran 1028 different combinations and they were seemingly random.

Comment: @MikeBaron that is interesting. Please give a look to this book: https://books.google.be/books?id=iMNNDwAAQBAJ&pg=SA2-PA13&lpg=SA2-PA13&dq=azureml+entire+grid+number+of+combination&source=bl&ots=D9jpfucIF8&sig=IE1NvcoKsGj-JIb2ixPbyPhwXWY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfmJ-jiYnfAhUJyaQKHbw3DCQQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=azureml%20entire%20grid%20number%20of%20combination&f=false 
 At page 12-13 it gives a bit more details on the validation that might help.